# Can not open qt creator project inside visual studio 2013, qt5widgetsd.dll is missing from your computer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, qt

when i try to debug a project that is created inside qtcreator using visual studio 2013 i get this error:

> **the program cant start because qt5widgetsd.dll is missing from your**
>   computer.

Please note that the missing dll is **qt5widgetsd.dll** not **qt5widgets.dll**
i open project using qt5/open qt project file
im using visual studio 2013 and qt 5.4.1.

Comment: Maybe you should tag it for Visual Studio 2013 instead of Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: I would start by looking at your Qt binary folder to see if qt5widgetsd.dll exists. If not you have a bad install or you did not build the debug dlls.

Comment: it is living in qtbase folder.

Comment: Do you have **qt5widgetsd.dll** in your program's bin or the folder your program's files are in ? if not, put it there or use dependency walker on your program to see the files it needs.

Comment: I had the same just after QT's installation and it resolved by doing the classic PC restart... very weird, unsure as to what caused this